# Android .putExtra (not responding)

Tags: android, string, put, extra

I need to pass a String created from 'Activity A' to 'Activity B' so that I can display it in a TextView.
The problem is that the code causes Android to not respond, its identical to the other tutorials online.

Thanks for any feedback.

**Activity A.onCreate()**

```
check_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_button);
    check_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(AddActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
            String hash = text_hash.toString();
            i.putExtra("hash" , hash);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

**Activity B.onCreate()**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null)
{
    passedHash = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getString("hash");
    hash.setText(passedHash);
}
```

stack trace:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: is text_hash a textView ?

Comment: Yes, see the edit to the Question :)

Comment: As @SajedulKarim said you should use String hash = text_hash.getText().toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log, it seems that you didn't initialize your TextView in Activity B. Do this before setting the text to your TextView:

```
TextView hash = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hash_textview);
```

Comment: Literally just figured this out. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

If `text_hash`  is `TextView` or `EditText` then use use

```
String hash = text_hash.getText().toString();
```

In `ActivityB` onCreate() use this:

```
String newString;
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("hash");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
From your error log, You didn't initialize TextView in your ActivityB. First you have to initialize that TextView then set Text.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I needed to use X.getText().toString();
By reading the stack trace I figured I also needed to findViewByID on the TextView BEFORE trying to set text.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

your textView object is nullreferenced, you need to initialize the hash variable in the oncreate before you begin to call any method of that TextView...

## Example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView hash = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hash_textview);
```

after that you can call the settext method

```
 hash.setText(passedHash);
```